# HTML Embedding Flash SWFObject using GET

Tags: html, flash, get, swfobject

I am trying to embed my flash game inside my HTML Code.
I got the embedding right, but now I want to use GET to get the ID from the url
this is the url I use :

```
http://localhost/directory/html/indexpage.php?id=3
```

I want to get the ID of the url using the embed code :

```
<head>
    <title> Widget </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.id = "3";

        var params = {};
        params.menu = "false";
        params.scale = "noscale";
        params.allowfullscreen = "false";

        var attributes = {};

        swfobject.embedSWF("flash/Flash.swf, "game", "398", "398", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>

    <link href="./mobile/styles/game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

I tried this :

```
swfobject.embedSWF("flash/Flash.swf?id=3", "game", "398", "398", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Flash doesn't parse the query string, probably for good reason. You need to pass in as flashvars. It's a common annoyance -- maybe SWFObject has improved since I last had to do this stuff (2012), but if not, I would tend to have code like this:

```
function parseQueryString() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var keyVals = query.split("&")
    var dict = {}
    for (var i=0; i<keyVals.length; i++)
    {
        var pair = keyVals[i].split("=");
        dict[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
    }
    return dict;
}
...

flashvars = parseQueryString(); // catchall
flashvars.foo = parsedQuery.foo; // more explicit is probably better
...
swfobject.embedSWF(
    "MyFlashThing.swf", "flashContent", 
    "800", "600", 
    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
    flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Comment: I Found out that if i replace 

    flashvars.id = "3";

with 

    flashvars.id = getURLParameter('id');

then the setting of the variable works.
and everything else does to.

It was as simple as that, i didn't know that haha

Comment: Where does getURLParameter() come from? Is that a SWFObject method?